# Total number of subgrids with cells colored red in time better than m*m*n

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, count

Given a grid, m*n, where each cell can be colored green or red, output the number of subgrids which have all the cells with the same color red in a time complexity better than m^2*n or m*n^2.

**Example**
Grid:

```
[[r, r, r, r], 
 [r, g, g, g],
 [r, r, r, r]]
```

where r represents red and g represents green
The output should be 24 for all sub-grids with only red cell(s).

A similar problem with code is found here: 
[Number of submatricies containing all zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089080/number-of-submatricies-containing-all-zeros)

However, the usage of segment tree  in the above solution and the statement "As you can see if we add all those numbers we will receive an answer for given histogram." are not clear me.
Could someone explain me any algorithm that is better than cubic?

Comment: If you have a question about that answer, first try to add a comment asking its writer for clarifications. The answer you refer to has zero votes, was not even accepted, was written by a person with a relatively low score, and is quite long. One needs a good reason to invest time understanding it.

Comment: An O(n^2) solution is given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-submatrices-with-all-1s/).

Comment: The O(n^2) gives 6 for the following: [[0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0]] when it should be 24, so I do not think the linked solution is correct

Comment: If you're counting 1's, it should be 6..

Comment: ahh, you are right!